# use uniqid id where general by spl_object_hash be array's key

Tags: php, arrays, object

today, when i use spl_object_hash() generate unique id be array's key, but the result doesn't like what i think...

```
class a
{

    public $i;

    public function __construct($i)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
    }

}

$array = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) 
{

    $a = new a(1);

    $array[spl_object_hash($a)] = $i;

}

var_dump($array);
```

the output is:

```
array(2) {

  '0000000053bd5300000000005432750f' =>
  int(2)

  '0000000053bd5303000000005432750f' =>
  int(1)
}
```

Code:

```
class a
{
    public $i;

    public function __construct($i)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
}
$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $a = new a(1);
    $array[spl_object_hash($a)] = $a;

}
var_dump($array);
```

the output is:

```
array(3) {

    '000000005397fe130000000045a81147' =>class a#1 (1) {
       public $i =>
       int(1)
    }

    '000000005397fe100000000045a81147' =>class a#2 (1) {
       public $i =>
       int(1)
    }

    '000000005397fe110000000045a81147' =>class a#3 (1) {
       public $i =>
       int(1)
    }

}
```

the display confused me; why output like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first comment in the docs for [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php):

> Note that the contents (properties) of the object are NOT hashed by the function, merely its internal handle and handler table pointer. This is sufficient to guarantee that any two objects simultaneously co-residing in memory will have different hashes. Uniqueness is not guaranteed between objects that did not reside in memory simultaneously, for example:
>
> var_dump(spl_object_hash(new stdClass()), spl_object_hash(new stdClass()));
>
> Running this alone will usually generate the same hashes, since PHP reuses the internal handle for the first stdClass after it has been dereferenced and destroyed when it creates the second stdClass.

Basically, every time you overwrite `$a` with a new object the reference to the first object is destroyed and the handle is reused for the new object. As a result `spl_object_hash()` returns the same hash.

To overcome this, assign each object to a new variable:

```
class a
{
    public $i;

    public function __construct($i)
    {
        $this->i = $i;
    }
}
$array = [];

$a = new a(1);
$array[spl_object_hash($a)] = $a;

$b = new a(1);
$array[spl_object_hash($b)] = $b;

$c = new a(1);
$array[spl_object_hash($c)] = $c;

var_dump($array);
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/629484)**

Comment: So, not very reliable then.

Comment: It's not in this scenario. Definitely a gotcha.